# Adding a new record in Access

Tags: java, ms-access

I had this working at one point, but changed the path along with some other fields and now I just cant seem to get it updating again. Here is the code:

```
public class DbUpdate{
    ResultSet rs;
    Statement st;

    public void DbUpdate(){
        Connect();
    }
    public void Connect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\User\\ugt\\Desktop\\ResourcePlanningTool_DB.accdb");
            st = con.createStatement();

            st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO AssignmentDetails (Name) VALUES('Bob Joll')");          

       }
       catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            DbUpdate x = new DbUpdate();
        }
}
```

At the moment the project runs without errors, but it doesn't seem to actually update the table. Also the path name is correct.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? And your file is at `C:\ResourcePlanningTool_DB.accdb`?

Comment: Updated - Sorry, part of the path got cut off when I pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `public void DbUpdate()` isn't quite a constructor and wasn't called. I removed the void and also added a `con.commit()` after the executeUpdate and it worked.

Edit: The commit doesn't seem to be needed.

```
        int retVal = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO AssignmentDetails (Name) VALUES('Bob Joll')");             
        System.out.println("Inserted: " + retVal);            
        //con.commit();
        //con.close();
```

Comment: It runs and prints 1, but the the info still isn't being saved in the database. Is there a save command I should be using?

Comment: It seems to save only if I use  rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM AssignmentDetails");  after I create the new entry.

Comment: @Crash It didn't work for me the first time either, so I added the commit line. After that it worked every time. I also closed are reopened access, access sometimes gets confused. I also kept the con.close line un-commented, that was a typo in my answer.